# Return _rev and _id in CouchDB _update function?

Tags: couchdb

Is there a way to return the newly created document's _rev and _id field to the client from an _update function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can, however the solution is not perfect.

You already know the document `_id` in the update function. Either you are computing it yourself, or using user input, or if you wish to let CouchDB produce an ID automatically, then use the `req.uuid` value.

```
function(doc, req) {
    // An example _update function.
    var id;

    id = "Whatever";   // Pick one yourself, or...
    id = req.query.id; // Let the user specify via ?id=whatever, or...
    id = req.body;     // Let the user specify via POST or PUT body, or...
    id = req.uuid;     // Use a random UUID from CouchDB

    var doc = {"_id":id, "other_stuff":"Whatever other data you have"};
    log("Document _id will be: " + doc._id);
    return([doc, {json: {"success":true, "doc":doc}]);
}
```

Unfortunately, you do not know the `_rev` in the show function. However, CouchDB will send it to the client in the HTTP header `X-Couch-Update-NewRev`.

For example:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
X-Couch-Update-NewRev: 1-967a00dff5e02add41819138abb3284d
Server: CouchDB/1.1.0 (Erlang OTP/R14B03)
Date: Tue, 12 Jul 2011 06:09:34 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 14

{"stuff":true}
```